# Add listner in root Config @EventListener

Tags: spring, spring-security

With the annotation `@EventListener`, do we still need to add a listner to `ServletContext` ?

Like this listener class:

```
@Component
public class LoginListener {

@Autowired
UserService us;

@EventListener
public void onApplicationEvent(AuthenticationSuccessEvent event) {

    String userName = ((UserDetails) event.getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getUsername();          

    System.out.println("lastloginspec : " + userName + " : 00 : " + LocalDateTime.now());

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I need it to do is register the `HttpSessionEventListener` in my `ServletContext`through `addListener method`

```
servletContext.addListener(new HttpSessionEventListener());
```